# How to replace URL encoding with nothing or space using .replace or regex

Tags: python, string, list

- My UI is sending %20 for space
- I need to replace %20 with space
- The incoming data may be string or list

Below are the condition need to satisfied

My input are input Lets say my search bar is searching below pattern

`ABC,%20CDE`  Expected out `ABC,CDE`

`ABC%20CDE`  Expected out `ABC CDE`

`ABC%20%20%20CDE`  Expected out `ABC CDE`

`[ABC,%20CDE]`  Expected out `[ABC,CDE]`

`ABC,%20%20%20`  Expected out `ABC`

`[ABC,%20%20%20]`  Expected out `[ABC]`

`[,%20%20%20CDE]`  Expected out `[CDE]`

`,%20%20%20CDE`  Expected out `CDE`

My Code only satisfied one condition

```
string.replace('%20',' ')
```

I am searching with replace. If not regex also would help

Comment: `text.replace('%20', ' ').strip().strip(',')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `s = ',%20%20%20CDE'`;
`s.replace('%20', ' ').strip() `    o/p `',   CDE'`
E0    `'CDE'`

Comment: `text.replace('%20', ' ').strip(", ")` - https://rextester.com/CZKU92290

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm of expected results ? There is a URL decoding. But what about the extra steps of removing spaces and `,` ?

Answer (score 1):

### Use `unquote` from `urlib.parse`

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote


unquote("ABC,%20CDE")       # 'ABC, CDE'
unquote("[ABC,%20CDE]")     # '[ABC, CDE]'
unquote("ABC%20CDE")        # 'ABC CDE'
unquote("ABC%20%20%20CDE")  # 'ABC   CDE'
unquote(",%20%20%20CDE")    # ',   CDE'
```

Then you can use `replace` to replace extra spaces.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: unquote(",%20%20%20CDE")  expected is 'CDE'